# PHP Curl scraping script not inserting data into DB ('syntax error')

Tags: php, mysql, adsense

I'm working on a PHP script with curl that logs into Google AdSense, scrapes a single string of data and inserts it into the database.

It's almost there. The script setups up the table, logs into AdSense just fine and can echo the resulting data. But it's not inserting it into the DB, so I think it's just a simple case of some bad code between lines 80-87 (below):

```
"INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE (
`id`, `earnings`, `gmt-plus-one`, `gmt-minus-eight`
) VALUES (
NULL, '"
. mysql_real_escape_string( $earnings ) . "', '"
. mysql_real_escape_string( $gmtPlusOne ) . "', '"
. mysql_real_escape_string( $gmtMinusEight ) . "' );" )
or die( mysql_error() );
```

Entire code: http://cl.ly/4rH0

Any help is warmly appreciated. Sorry for being such a newb.

Answer (score 0):

@Keith Mander: Try

```
"INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE (
`earnings`, `gmt-plus-one`, `gmt-minus-eight`
) VALUES ('"
. mysql_real_escape_string( $earnings ) . "', '"
. mysql_real_escape_string( $gmtPlusOne ) . "', '"
. mysql_real_escape_string( $gmtMinusEight ) . "' );" )
or die( mysql_error() );
```

Comment: Many thanks for the attempt stealthyninja. Unfortunately, still no cigar. I get the "unable to log-in properly" coded error.

Comment: @Keith Mander: As in your own custom error in the full version of your code and not a MySQL error? It's not your SQL then, it's your second `preg_match` not finding a match and failing.

Answer (score 0):

From your complete script at http://cl.ly/4rH0/adsense_earnings2.php it becomes apparent that `$DB_TABLE` does not exist. It was defined as constant initially, and this is why the SQL query is failing.

You must rewrite it into:

```
  mysql_query(
         "INSERT INTO " . DB_TABLE . " (
                 `id`, `earnings`, `gmt-plus-one`, `gmt-minus-eight`
                 ) VALUES (
                 NULL, '"
                 . mysql_real_escape_string( $earnings ) . "', '"
                 . mysql_real_escape_string( $gmtPlusOne ) . "', '"
                 . mysql_real_escape_string( $gmtMinusEight ) . "' );" )
          or die( mysql_error() );
```

Unreleated note: the mysql_ functions are really cumbersome. You should think about moving to PDO and prepared statments, which would compact above query quite a lot.

Comment: "unable to log-in properly" - I think I'm doomed on this one :/

Comment: @Keith: You should not use curl anyway. If the site depends on a login, try Zend_Http with a in-memory CookieJar. Or ty phpQuery if you are into scraping anyway.